# Silence ActionView::Template::Errors, like "isn't precompiled"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, actionview

my question is about the standard behavior of the action-view gem when using the rails asset-pipeline.

It throws an Exception and the app-execution stops whenever there's an image which isn't precompiled, so the user just gets to see the standard blank page saying: "... something went wrong".

Something as trivial as a missing image (could be an icon, maybe with just a misspelled name...) shouldn't be a showstopper. Should it be?!

We would like to change this radical behavior to a more mild version: Having the app continue working, but, of course, notifying us about the missing image.

***Question:***

Is there any other way then monkeypatching the relevant part of the helper method contained in the action-view gem?

Is there any config we could modify so there would be no need for this patch?

Having this kind of monkeypatch is considered a  maintenance nightmare in case of gem-updates, isn't it?

This is our actual patch: called: "assetpipe_easy_errors.rb" residing in `config/initializers`, the relevant method is "`digest_for`"

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths.class_eval do
        attr_accessor :asset_environment, :asset_prefix, :asset_digests, :compile_assets, :digest_assets

        class AssetNotPrecompiledError < StandardError; end

        def asset_for(source, ext)
          source = source.to_s
          return nil if is_uri?(source)
          source = rewrite_extension(source, nil, ext)
          asset_environment[source]
        rescue Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths
          nil
        end

        def digest_for(logical_path)
          if digest_assets && asset_digests && (digest = asset_digests[logical_path])
            return digest
          end

          if compile_assets
            if digest_assets && asset = asset_environment[logical_path]
              return asset.digest_path
            end
            return logical_path
          else
            #original code: raise AssetNotPrecompiledError.new("#{logical_path} isn't precompiled")
            ### own Patch: these next four lines:
            Rails.logger.info(" arrg!! an image is missing ")
            ### example: FeedbackMailer.generic_system_message(subject,bodytext).deliver
            FeedbackMailer.generic_system_message("asset error",logical_path).deliver
            return logical_path
          end
        end

        def rewrite_asset_path(source, dir, options = {})
          if source[0] == ?/
            source
          else
            if digest_assets && options[:digest] != false
              source = digest_for(source)
            end
            source = File.join(dir, source)
            source = "/#{source}" unless source =~ /^\//
            source
          end
        end

        def rewrite_extension(source, dir, ext)
          source_ext = File.extname(source)
          if ext && source_ext != ".#{ext}"
            if !source_ext.empty? && (asset = asset_environment[source]) &&
                  asset.pathname.to_s =~ /#{source}\Z/
              source
            else
              "#{source}.#{ext}"
            end
          else
            source
          end
        end
end
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated